# Use comma-separated list for IN statement as parameter

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm trying to use parameters in a sql statement that uses the IN operator.
The use of that statement is to delete any memberships of a group that are NOT in the list, so my code is as follows ...

```
    const accessGroupId = 1;         // Access Group
    const membershipIds = [1, 2, 3]; // Keep those IDs, delete all others

    Database.run(`
        DELETE
        FROM AccessGroup
        WHERE
            accessGroupId = $accessGroupId AND
            membershipId NOT IN ($membershipIds);`,
        {
            $accessGroupId: accessGroupId,
            $membershipIds: membershipIds.join(",")
        }
    );
```

What I want this statement to look like after the parameters are resolved is this ...

```
    DELETE
    FROM AccessGroup
    WHERE
        accessGroupId = 1 AND
        membershipId NOT IN (1,2,3);
```

This does however not work as expected. Instead of only deleting entries from the access group 1 where the membership id is NOT 1, 2 or 3, all entries for the access group are getting deleted.

The code does work as expected if I change it the following way and concatenate the statement per hand ...

```
    const accessGroupId = 1;         // Access Group
    const membershipIds = [1, 2, 3]; // Keep those IDs, delete all others

    Database.run(`
        DELETE
        FROM AccessGroup
        WHERE
            accessGroupId = $accessGroupId AND
            membershipId NOT IN (${membershipIds.join(",")});`,
        {
            $accessGroupId: accessGroupId
        }
    );
```

Since this is working, something must break with the comma-seperated list when it's passed as a parameter.

If at all possible, I would like to use parameters for everything.
Does someone know why this does not work?

Comment: This is a tricky problem in any programming language.  Question: Do you know the maximum number of terms which might appear inside the `IN` clause?

Comment: Usually it is easier passing the list as xml or transform it to xml and make a select on it. Cant tell you the syntax in `sqlite` tho.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I do not, but it should be more than the 3 I'm trying to get it to work with. I don't think the amount of terms in the IN statement is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert in JavaScript, but I know that:

```
membershipIds.join(",")
```

returns a string, so that your final query looks like this:

```
DELETE FROM AccessGroup
WHERE accessGroupId = 1 
  AND membershipId NOT IN ('1,2,3');
```

So, the list of the `IN` operator contains only 1 value, the string: `'1,2,3'` and all the `membershipId`s are compared to this value and since none of them matches it then all the rows of `accessGroupId = 1` are deleted.

As an alternative you can use the operator `LIKE`:

```
Database.run(`
    DELETE FROM AccessGroup
    WHERE accessGroupId = $accessGroupId 
      AND ',' || $membershipIds || ',' NOT LIKE '%,' || membershipId || ',%'`,
    {
        $accessGroupId: accessGroupId,
        $membershipIds: membershipIds.join(",")
    }
);
```